# add array of object into array of object using forEach es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this set of colors array `["#c4b18f", "#100f5c"]`

and I want to add to each cameras, but the cameras is a nested array, like so

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "Sat",
    "cameras": [
      {
        "name": "East Gate",
        "total_count": 233
      },
      {
        "name": "South Gate",
        "total_count": 2599
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "Sun",
    "cameras": [
      {
        "name": "East Gate",
        "total_count": 123342
      },
      {
        "name": "South Gate",
        "total_count": 2333
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried but I got undefined

```
const result = data.forEach(obj => ({
                ...obj,
                cameras: obj.cameras.map((obj2, i) => ({
                    ...obj2,
                    color: colors[i]
                }))
            }))
```

I suspect I forgot to return something, or I should use map instead of forEach for the first loop?

Comment: I think you meant to do `.map` instead of `.forEach`.

Comment: The [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals) is not ES6, it is a stage 3 proposal currently. Are you sure you're not getting a syntax error?

Comment: what is your expected final data format ?

Comment: Why do you add duplicated data to each cameras field? Can it be a object reference?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I use babel so it's fine

Answer (score 0):

**Array.map**

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate each element and return a new array.

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

In the example below, we are calling **map()** *twice*. Once for the array of objects (days) and then each time we find a cameras array.

```
let addColors = (days, colors) => days.map(o => {
  o.cameras = o.cameras.map( (c, i) => {
    c.colors = colors[i%colors.length];
    return c;
  });
  return o;
});
```

> what if I have 3 color or more, will this solution work?

It will work by changing this line `c.colors = colors[i%colors.length];` It uses the [Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) operator. For each camera, it divides the index by the number of colors and uses the remainder as the index for the color array.

This is a little difficult to explain.

Cameras looks like this:

```
 "cameras": [{
    "name": "East Gate",
    "total_count": 123342
  },
  {
    "name": "South Gate",
    "total_count": 2333
  }
]
```

East Gate cameras has an index of `0` and South Gate cameras has an index of `1`. So we divide 0 by the number of colors (I changed the example so we have 7 cameras). It goes into 0, 0 times with no remainder. So we choose `colors[0]` which is `red`. Next, we divide 1 by 7. It goes into 1, 0 times and has a remainder of 1. So we choose `colors[1]` which is `orange`. This could continue for each set of cameras. If the number of cameras was longer than the number of colors, then the color choices would start to repeat.

I expanded the example below to show what happens when you have more cameras than colors.

**Runnable Example**

```js
let colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
let foo = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "Sat",
    "cameras": [{
        "name": "East Gate",
        "total_count": 233
      },
      {
        "name": "South Gate",
        "total_count": 2599
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "Sun",
    "cameras": [{
        "name": "East Gate",
        "total_count": 123342
      },
      {
        "name": "South Gate",
        "total_count": 2333
      },
      {
        "name": "North Gate",
        "total_count": 2234
      },
      {
        "name": "West Gate",
        "total_count": 2234
      },
      {
        "name": "North West Gate",
        "total_count": 2234
      },
      {
        "name": "North East Gate",
        "total_count": 2234
      },
      {
        "name": "South West Gate",
        "total_count": 2234
      },
      {
        "name": "South East Gate",
        "total_count": 2234
      }
    ]
  }
];

let addColors = (days, colors) => days.map(o => {
  o.cameras = o.cameras.map( (c, i) => {
    c.colors = colors[i%colors.length];
    return c;
  });
  return o;
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(addColors(foo, colors), null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: hmm 1 color for 1 camera only

Comment: Then use the map index and mod 2 to pick one or the other. I modified the code above.

Comment: what if I have 3 color or more, will this solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use for loop. The code below will help. Let arr be the initial array.

```
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
        var cameras = arr[j]["cameras"];
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
            cameras[i]["color"]=["#c4b18f", "#100f5c"]
        }
    }
```